# Error in REST call using WebClient in Spring Framework

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am trying to make a REST call using WebClient, however I am not able to pass the request body. it is showing error as - the method syncBody(body) is undefined for the type capture #1-of?

```
public static String getResult(Body body) {

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();

         String result= webClient.get()
                       .uri(URL)
                       .syncBody(body)
                       .retrieve()
                       .bodyToMono(String.class)
                       .block();


}
```

it is showing error as - the method syncBody(body) is undefined for the type capture #1-of?

Comment: do you have a body in a get request?

Comment: yes, there is, it takes in a JSON as the payload, its an external api

Comment: I forgot to thank you, i had to change it to post to make it work. @pedrohreis

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but I do not think you can use `WebClient`. Actually, in spring boot 2.0.5 this is not even compiling.

What happens is that when you invoke `.get()` you get an instance of `RequestHeadersUriSpec` that does not have support for `body` or `syncBody` methods, while when invoking `post` (or `put`, etc) you get an instance of `RequestBodyUriSpec` that does